# Problema com Português no ADT

Tags: java, android, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação

Eu estou trabalhando num *App Android*, e um amigo meu me mandou o *app* que ele trabalhou, mas teve um problema, todos os caracteres da nossa língua como o "ç" viraram coisas tipo c'@%, evidenciando problema na codificação/tradução. Queria saber se isso pode se relacionar com o idioma do meu Eclipse quando eu o instalei ou o que.

Tentei recompilar, mas o Banco de Dados que estávamos usando(interno) não está sendo modificado, está sendo dito que eu estou definindo duas `Primary Keys`, mas eu não o estou fazendo, alguém sabe o que está acontecendo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr o erro que estão me mostrando é este:
                                                          03-23 19:32:02.536: E/Database(332): Failure 19 (PRIMARY KEY must be unique) on 0x92ba0 when executing 'INSERT INTO "tipo" VALUES(1,"ESTADUAL");'

Answer (score 1):

Sem mais informações não dá pra dizer o que está acontecendo, mas posso afirmar duas coisas:

1. O idioma do Eclipse não tem nada a ver - mas o *encoding* **dos arquivos fonte** - pode ter. O compilador Java (`javac`) aceita um parâmetro `-encoding` e, segundo [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9248267/520779), o Eclipse tem uma opção pra você informar isso ao compilador (não uso Eclipse há muito tempo, então não sei dizer onde).

   Confira (usando um outro editor de texto, por exemplo) se a codificação dos seus arquivos é diferente da codificação do computador onde o programa está sendo compilado. Se for, especifique esse parâmetro no Eclipse, passando a codificação correta.
2. Isso do banco de dados não tem nada a ver com o problema que você está experimentando. Se tem uma segunda dificuldade não relacionada, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta acrescentando os detalhes relevantes.

Dito isso, é provável que seu problema não seja com encoding em tempo de compilação (mas cheque o item 1 só pra ter certeza), e sim na hora de exibir as strings na tela ou algo assim. Por favor isole na sua aplicação o trecho que está com o resultado incorreto, e edite sua pergunta mostrando-o, para podermos ajudá-lo mais. Por exemplo, verifique qual campo está apresentando esse problema, e procure pelo trecho de código que popula esse campo e/ou o imprime na tela.

Comment: Adicionei o erro que estou tendo num comentário.

Comment: @user3256631 Eu continuo sem entender o que seu problema com o banco de dados tem a ver com o problema das letras acentuadas. Está me parecendo duas coisas independentes. Provavelmente o caso do banco é porque o script que popula o BD está sendo executado duas vezes, não sei... Abra uma pergunta separada pra isso, não vale a pena misturar as duas coisas se elas não tem relação nenhuma uma com a outra (e se a pergunta ficar muita ampla, ela acabará sendo fechada como tal)

Comment: segui seu conselho e fiz uma pergunta única:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10276/problema-com-banco-de-dados-interno