# Problema com Banco de Dados interno

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando manipular um banco de dados interno com o seguinte código:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tipo ([codigo] integer autoincrement,nome text not null);"; 
bancoDados.execSQL(sql);
sql = "INSERT INTO \"tipo\" VALUES(1,\"ESTADUAL\");";
bancoDados.execSQL(sql);
sql = "INSERT INTO \"tipo\" VALUES(2,\"MUNICIPAL\");";
bancoDados.execSQL(sql);
sql = "INSERT INTO \"tipo\" VALUES(3,\"PRIVADA\");";
bancoDados.execSQL(sql);
sql = "INSERT INTO \"tipo\" VALUES(4,\"FEDERAL\");";
```

O erro que estou tendo é o seguinte:

```
03-23 20:22:26.419: E/Database(368): 
Failure 19 (PRIMARY KEY must be unique) on 0x92ba0 when executing 
'INSERT INTO "tipo" VALUES(1,"ESTADUAL");'
```

Eu já tentei algumas coisas: tirar o número que eu mesmo estava inserindo (por estar com um autoincrement), mas não deu e continuou o mesmo erro... Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Comment: No INSERT ou você coloca a lista de campos (omitindo o campo codigo que será gerado automaticamente) ou terá que informar o valor de todos os campos (o que você não fez no primeiro INSERT). Limpe sua tabela e refaça os INSERTs de uma única forma. Para verificar o que foi incluído rode um SELECT * FROM "tipo" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu banco de dados está vazio? Seu campo `código` é auto-incremento, então se tiver um único registro que seja então o código `1` já estará "ocupado". O ideal quando se lida com campos desse tipo é deixar que o próprio sistema atribua os códigos/IDs para você:

```
INSERT INTO "tipo"(nome) VALUES("ESTADUAL");
INSERT INTO "tipo"(nome) VALUES("MUNICIPAL");
INSERT INTO "tipo"(nome) VALUES("PRIVADA");
INSERT INTO "tipo"(nome) VALUES("FEDERAL");
```

Usando essa sintaxe você atribui somente um [ou mais] campo específico, omitindo aqueles que não precisam ser atribuídos.

Nota: se esse for um script pra popular o banco de dados, talvez seja o caso de não executá-lo mais de uma vez. Caso contrário, cada vez que você o fizer uma nova linha será criada para cada um deles, de novo e de novo...

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo! Eu não tava percebendo esses erros bobos que eu tava cometendo, tava pensando que podia ser problema do SQL Server, tava pirando... Arrumei as coisas e agora tá dando tudo certo, valeu mesmo!